# Make google now card like search animations?

Tags: android, layout, google-now

I have an app with a search bar and want the results to pop up from the button in the form of cards, similar to the ones of Google now. Each result(card) will contain its own information including an image. There is no need for the swipe to remove parts of it. Users should be able to just scroll through the results.
After around 3-4 result cards are scrolled the next set of results should pop up just like how you would scroll in Google now.

What is the easiest way by which I can achieve this?

Is it possible to create a layout prefab or something that I can populate with results from a database and then pull on to the screen?

Please help !